# how do I access to an element of a GeoJSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, geojson

I'm looking to access to every properties of my `geoJson`.

For example, how do I  access to `geoJson.features.properties.messagePerso`?

I want to be able with something like innerHTML to display the `messagePerso` in `div` and to go from one to another with a button.

```
var geojson = {

"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "message": " url(img/1.jpg) 50% 50%",
            "messagePerso": " croisement des canaux sambre/bxl-charleroi",
            "iconSize": [20,20]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              4.427333,50.413140
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "message":" url(img/13.jpg) 50% 50%",
             "messagePerso": "Saint théodore Est/ Vue sur carsid désafecté",
            "iconSize": [20,20]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
        4.418988,50.417823
            ]
        }
    }
```

For now I used the json files to create some dots on my map and use them as buttons to display some elements of the json files with something like

```
id.innerHTML = marker.properties.message;
```

But how to make a single button that display the next `marker.properties.message`?

```
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
var yoo = $('.marker').length;

 $('.marker').each( function(i){
 $(this).attr('id','marker'+(i))
 });
el.style.width ='15px';
el.style.height = '15px';

el.style.opacity =0;

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
 numlegende2.innerHTML = marker.properties.message;
 map.flyTo({center:marker.geometry.coordinates});   
});
  });
```

Comment: Where will the button be at?

Comment: what you mean by at?  the button will be in the html , on the map. Was it the question?